# How to rewrite given query in jpql custom query?

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa, jpql

I have a mysql query which look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `HOST` WHERE `DATE_OF_SCAN` between 
(SELECT subtime((Select max(`DATE_OF_SCAN`) from `HOST` ), '0 0:5:0'))
and
(Select max(`DATE_OF_SCAN`) from `HOST` );
```

which basically is returning hosts from range of max date in table and (max date - 5 min).

I'm trying to rewrite it in the jpql:

```
@Query("SELECT h FROM Host h WHERE h.date between "
        + "(SELECT subtime((Select max(ho.date) from Host ho ), 0 0:5:0)) "
        + "and (Select max(hos.date) from Host hos)")
public List<Host> findHosts();
```

but it is constantly throwing exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: 0 near line 1, column 126 [SELECT h FROM com.iie.model.Host h WHERE h.date between (SELECT subtime((Select max(ho.date) from com.iie.model.Host ho ), 0 0:5:0)) and (Select max(hos.date) from com.iie.model.Host hos)]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:276)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1537)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:285)
```

finally. I've tried to pass the '0 0:5:0' as a parameter, but it throws an exception that this is not a proper Joda DateTime format.

The Host:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "HOST")
public class Host {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "HOST_ID")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "HOSTNAME")
    private String hostname;
    @Column(name = "IP")
    private String ip;
    @Column(name = "DATE_OF_SCAN")
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    private DateTime date;

    public Host(Long id, String hostname, String ip, DateTime date) {
        this.id = id;
        this.hostname = hostname;
        this.ip = ip;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Host(String hostname, String ip, DateTime date) {
        this.hostname = hostname;
        this.ip = ip;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Host() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getHostname() {
        return hostname;
    }

    public void setHostname(String hostname) {
        this.hostname = hostname;
    }

    public String getIp() {
        return ip;
    }

    public void setIp(String ip) {
        this.ip = ip;
    }

    public DateTime getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(DateTime date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this part is not valid SQL

```
SELECT h FROM Host h
```

I suggest changing to explicit column names

```
SELECT h.mycolumn FROM Host h
```

Comment: Hmm, that is way strange, I've been using queries which starts like this in every other repository and it was working ok. I'm begining to think that this '0 0:5:0' is messed up